# Keeping public header simple through inheritance

Tags: c++

I am writing a parsing library, where I have public headers shared with some larger software. One of the headers is a data-containing object, let's call it DataObject. The object has some fields of type size_t, float, and std::string.

The way the parser is designed, it will expect setters to take a string value as an argument, and the setter should try to convert the value to the designated data type. If the conversion fails, the parser will exit and return an error message that an unexpected type was found.

However, these setters should not be in the public header available to the larger software. It should remain clean and only contain setters with arguments matching the data type of said member.

To solve this I have created a child struct of DataObject, let's call it DataObjectChild, that is NOT public and available to the larger software, in which I put my setters needed by the parser.

Simple example:

DataObject.h

```
class DataObject {
public:
   void setValue1(size_t value) { this->value1 = value; }
   size_t getValue1() { return this->value1; }

   void setValue2(size_t value) { this->value2 = value; }
   size_t getValue2() { return this->value2; }

private:
   size_t value1, value2; 
}
```

DataObjectChild.h

```
struct DataObjectChild : public DataObject {
   void setValue1(std::string value) { this->value1 = std::stoi(value); }

   void setValue2(std::string value) { this->value2 = std::stoi(value); }
}
```

1. Is this commonly used or it is just plain bad practice?
2. If so, does it have a name?

Comment: I can't answer this question, but let me just note that your `DataObjectChild::setValue1` hides the method `DataObject::setValue1`. You probably don 't want to do this! To avoid this, add `using DataObject::setValue1` to your `DataObjectChild`.

Comment: To keep a public header really simple use the pimpl pattern. The public header should not contain any implementation (details). The benefit is that you also have a "compilation firewall" ensuring you can change the implementation without having to change your clients. Also, Inheritance is usually not the solution ;)

Comment: Also, `private` fields in your `DataObject` won't work! The exact way you fix this problem may be important! Please make a [mcve], including usage.

Comment: ¿What is the point of `DataObjectChild` if clients will operate with `DataObject`?

Comment: @user7860670 I don't want the setters taking std::string as an argument inside the public header, it is ONLY necessary for the parser.

Comment: @Spencer I do, could you elaborate on how it would help in this scenario?

Comment: @anatolyg I am aware of this. But is of minor importance in my case. DataObject::setValue1 is never used inside the private parts of the library since the parser will pass the data by std::string to DataObjectChild in any case.

Comment: I just want to remind you on [mcve]. I think this question is unclear without it.

Comment: Actually, what's going on here is a fat interface due to poor separation of concepts.  You shouldn't have the string-setters all.  Let the parser, or even a helper class do the conversion from string to the internal value types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to expose only this interface:

```
void setValue1(size_t value);
size_t getValue1();
```

you could provide an abstract class

```
class DataObject {
public:
    virtual ~DataObject();
    virtual void setValue1(size_t value) = 0;
    virtual size_t getValue1()           = 0;
};
```

and a factory that gives your users the concrete object with specific implementation

```
std::unique_ptr<DataObject> createDataObject(args ...);
```

Or you can use [pointer to implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) idiom, then you can allow your user to create the object directly

```
class DataObject {
public:
    ~DataObject();  // if you need, make it virtual
    void setValue1(size_t value);
    size_t getValue1();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<DataObjectImpl> _pImpl;
};

//cpp

class DataObjectImpl {};  // implement it here

DataObject::~DataObject() = default; // destructor definition after impl class definition

void DataObject::setValue1(size_t value) {
    _pImpl->whatever();
    // ....
}
size_t DataObject::getValue1() {
    _pImpl->whatever();
    // ....
}
```

In case of your non-polymorphic example it would be difficult to generalize and hide the implementation.

Comment: Yep, good point, added DTor definition to the answer.